# PuTTY compile with VS2015 - flat style

Tags: c++, visual-studio, putty

I'm fixing a few things in the current SNAPSHOT version of Putty but I'm getting slightly another putty (design) than Simon Tatham does.

Please have a look to the following Screenshot.
First my own compiled PuTTY.exe (acutally the change was the window size - I need it broader...)
Second the original one.

[image]

My version has the "old-fashioned" XP-Style 3D-Effects, while the original variant already takes care of the new "flatstlye"-Window-Style.

I was looking for any property I can set or anything I can configure in Visual Studio, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything.

Thanks in advance for any reply!

P.S.: Trying to run perl mkfiles.py it generates no Makefile.cyg using Windows 10 and cygwin/cygwin64 for me. Maybe using another compiler would work in the end....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't add a manifest to your project.

See `windows\putty.mft` in PuTTY repository.

See also:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4987/Using-Windows-XP-Styles-in-your-MFC-WIN32-Applicat

Comment: I added a modern style Windows desktop app project template to Visual Studio 2015 long ago. It can serve as example code. It's available in the new project dialog (in the online templates).

Comment: @Martin thanks! It was indeed the missing mft file - editing the putty subproject: Configuration Properties / Manifest Tool / Input and Output / Additional Manifest Files: ..\..\putty.mft